# Regex get all quoted words that are not also single quoted

Tags: javascript, regex

Would it be possible to get all quoted text with a single regex?

Example text from regexr:

> Edit the "Expression" & Text to see matches. Roll over "matches" or the expression for details. 
>   Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. 
>   Save 'Favorites & "Share" expressions' with friends or the Community. "Explore" your results with Tools. A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.

In this case I would like to capture `Expression`, `matches` and `Explore` but not `Share` since `'Favorites & "Share" expressions'` is single quoted.

Comment: `"Explore"` is missed from result?

Comment: Oops, yes Explorer should be catched as well

Comment: You probably nead only this `".*?"`

Comment: He need look ahead and behind for no ' wrappers @MaciejKozieja

Comment: Is there any balance to the quotes or are they just first come, first serve ? Like `Is this "quote start '"quote middle, or "' quote end"`

Comment: @sln There is no balance

Comment: So, means you can't reliably find quoted strings. First come, first serve = you'll probably miss stuff.

Comment: So far the accepted answer seems to work fine with quite massive test files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build a regex that matches only the parts you want in Javascript, however you can build a pattern that matches all the string without gaps and use a capture group to extract the part you want:

```
/[^"']*(?:'[^']*'[^"']*)*"([^"]*)"/g
#^----------------------^ all that isn't content between double quotes
```

Since your string may end with something like `abcd 'efgh "ijkl" mnop' qrst` *(in short without the part you want but with a double quote part inside single quote substring)*, It's more secure to change the pattern to:

```
/[^"']*(?:'[^']*(?:'[^"']*|$))*(?:"([^"]*)"|$)/g
```

and to discard the last match.

Comment: I get the following results from executing this one: 

[ "Edit the "Expression"", "Expression" ]

Comment: @Xeul: you need to extract the capture group 1, to do that you must use `RegExp.prototype.exec` and not `String.prototype.match`. You can see how to use it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: Yes I'm doing /[^"']*(?:'[^']*'[^"']*)*"([^"]*)"/g.exec(content)

Comment: @Xeul: and the capture group 1 is the second item in your array. One more time read carefully the doc to see how `RegExp.prototype.exec` works and how to use it for multiple matches. See the examples.

Comment: then this solution only captures the first quoted text?

Answer (score 0):

Without special regex pattern:

```
var mystr = "Edit the \"Expression\" & Text to see matches. Roll over \"matches\" or the expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. Save 'Favorites & \"Share\" expressions' with friends or the Community. \"Explore\" your results with Tools. A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial."
var myarr = mystr.split(/\"/g)
var opening=false;
for(var i=1; i<myarr.length;i=i+2){
    if((myarr[i-1].length-myarr[i-1].replace(/'/g,"").length)%2===1){opening=!opening;}
    if(!opening){console.log(myarr[1]);}
}
```

How works:

- split text by `"`
- odd index is string with `"` wrapper
- if before this index, odd numbers of `'` exists, this item wrapped by `'` and should not be considered